# How to check packets on Not Attached Wireshark

Tags: virtualbox, wireshark, wannacrypt

I am currently running Windows 7 VirtualBox on my Windows 10 host. However, I do not want to connect them to each other since I need to check the packages being transferred when WannaCry is running. So, is there any way of safely attaching my computer to any of the options without WannaCry sending packages outside of the VirtualBox?

Comment: You do NOT want to give the virus access to the internet, since you are liable for any damage that it does and can be branded as a criminal, not mentioning that the virus may upgrade itself via the internet. You also do NOT want it to access your local network. So what are you going to measure?

Comment: I just need to take screenshots of the LLMNR packets transferred during the attack, however, when I sandbox it with "Host-only" Wireshark won't show any packets being transferred

Comment: You don't have internet access, which is what it needs, and I don't know how to fake it.